# Does the sort method in Javascript not work in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers

I am doing a code challenge and I am trying to compare each number in my sorted array to another number because they can't match. I am having trouble completing this challenge because even though my console log correctly prints the sorted array before I use it in the for loop, once I use it in the for loop the array seems to retain its original (unsorted)order. Here's the code:

```
function minMinMax(array) {
    let minAbsent = 0 
    // sort the array from smallest to largest
    let smallestToLargest = array.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    console.log(smallestToLargest)
    const smallest = smallestToLargest[0]
    // sort the array from largest to smallest
    let largestToSmallest = array.sort((a, b) => b - a)
    const largest = largestToSmallest[0]
    // use second smallest number as starting point for loop, then after each number check 
    // to see if that number is in the array, if not then add the value to our array
    for (i = 1, j = smallestToLargest[1]; i < smallestToLargest.length; i++, j++) {
      if (j !== smallestToLargest[i]) {
        minAbsent = j
        }
        console.log(smallestToLargest[i])
        console.log('this is the min absent ' + minAbsent)
      }
    return [smallest, minAbsent, largest]
  }
```

When the second console.log prints it reads back the given array (with the original order of numbers, as opposed to the sorted one). So what gives?

Comment: Can you create a snippet so we can run and check the results, please?

Comment: Also, you know that in stackoverflow you must mark correct answers as the "correct answer", right? All your questions have any correct answer checked actually.

Comment: `sort` method _**mutates**_ an array. So at the end `smallestToLargest` and `largestToSmallest` reference to the same array

Comment: do yourself a favor and define i and j

Comment: what is the test case/result for this?

Comment: @hindmost thank you! Of course it's in the docs and I didn't care to read them. Sorry for wasting ya'lls time!

Answer (score 0):

```
let descend = Object.assign([], array);
```

The above line won't copy the array by reference.

```
function minMinMax(array) {
  let minAbsent = 0;
  let descend = Object.assign([], array);
  // sort the array from smallest to largest
  let smallestToLargest = array.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  console.log(smallestToLargest)
  const smallest = smallestToLargest[0]
  // sort the array from largest to smallest
  let largestToSmallest = descend.sort((a, b) => b - a)
  const largest = largestToSmallest[0]
  // use second smallest number as starting point for loop, then after each number check 
  // to see if that number is in the array, if not then add the value to our array
  for (i = 1, j = smallestToLargest[1]; i < smallestToLargest.length; i++, j++) {
    if (j !== smallestToLargest[i]) {
      minAbsent = j
    }
    console.log(smallestToLargest[i])
    console.log('this is the min absent ' + minAbsent)
  }
  return [smallest, minAbsent, largest]
}
```

I think this would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is that although you have three separate pointers, "array", "smallestToLargest," and "largestToSmallest," they are all referencing the same actual array object.  "array.sort(...)" sorts the array that calls the method **and returns a reference to the same array**.

If you try logging smallestToLargest to the console after creating largestToSmallest, you'll see that smallestToLargest will print in descending order -- because it is getting sorted in descending order when the second array.sort is called.

```
let smallestToLargest = array.sort((a, b) => a - b)
console.log(smallestToLargest);
const smallest = smallestToLargest[0]
// sort the array from largest to smallest
let largestToSmallest = array.sort((a, b) => b - a)
console.log(smallestToLargest);
```

Tested on a random array, this yields:

```
[1, 3, 14, 29, 311, 323]
[323, 311, 29, 14, 3, 1]
```

To preserve the "smallestToLargest" array, you could **clone it by using "slice(0)"**.

**Try this:**

```
function minMinMax(array) {
    let minAbsent = 0 
    // sort the array from smallest to largest
    let smallestToLargest = array.sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(0);
    console.log(smallestToLargest);
    const smallest = smallestToLargest[0]
    // sort the array from largest to smallest
    let largestToSmallest = array.sort((a, b) => b - a).slice(0);
    console.log(smallestToLargest);
    const largest = largestToSmallest[0]
    // use second smallest number as starting point for loop, then after each number check 
    // to see if that number is in the array, if not then add the value to our array
    for (i = 1, j = smallestToLargest[1]; i < smallestToLargest.length; i++, j = smallestToLargest[i]) {
      if (j !== smallestToLargest[i]) {
        minAbsent = j
        }
        console.log(smallestToLargest[i])
        console.log('this is the min absent ' + minAbsent)
      }
  console.log(smallestToLargest);
    return [smallest, minAbsent, largest]
  };
```